Whats is the source of the Baal Shem Tov going to meet the Or Hachaim
BH
I heard there is a story of the Baal Shem Tov going to meet the Or Hachaim what is the source of this story?

It is a chassidic tradition from the Baal Shem Tov

It was not an actual visit in this material world. They met when they both ascended to the upper worlds in ירושלים של מעלה.

What’s the source of all this from what book?

The story can be found here: https://ascentofsafed.com/cgi-bin/ascent.cgi?Name=401-44

The story is found in countless places, but it's true origins are saught

The story is recounted in Degel Machaneh Efrayim, Shivchi HaBaal Shem Tov, and elsewhere. (The real story is that the Baal Shem Tov tried to meet the Orach Chayim but was prevented from doing so.)
